# Running GraphQL server on Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, graphql, graphql-js

In node.js to run the endpoint locally, I use the following snippet in my app.js

```
app.use('/graphql', (0, _expressGraphql2.default)(function (req) {
  return {
    schema: _schema2.default,
    pretty: true,
    context: _extends({ db: _models2.default }, (0, _isUser2.default)(req.headers['authorization'].split(' ')[1]))
  };
}));
app.listen(8080, function () {
```

However, my app isn't receiving any response from the endpoint on trying to reach hostname:8080/graphql. This works on my local machine.

Comment: What does your app.yaml file look like? How are your routes set up?

Comment: app.yaml is of the following form: runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: default

Comment: I think the snippet presented in the original question description should suffice for the clarification regarding routes. I am able to access the endpoint through https://<project>.appspot-preview.com/graphql but if i change listening port to anything other than 8080 say 3000, https://<project>.appspot-preview.com:3000/graphql doesn't work. I have added 3000 to be allowed in firewall restrictions from any source. I might be missing a step due to lack of any documentation. If something else like port forwarding or setting up routes in another way is required, would be glad if you could guide me

Answer (score 1):

The title of your post indicates that your node.js app is deployed in Google App Engine. There is no need to worry about assigning an IP address to your instance in that environment. Instances are managed by the App Engine, and so is the routing of requests to your application.

To access the app, once deployed to the App Engine, one only needs to address it following the pattern: app_name.appspot.com. Alternatively, for a custom domain, you can follow the “Using Custom Domains and SSL” guide [1]. Sub-chapter “Adding SSL to your custom domain” of this document may help you with the setting up of SSL, if needed.

The app listens on port 8080 by default in the app engine. This is of no concern to an outside caller, who can only use the following the pattern: app_name.appspot.com to call the app. This situation is valid for the app engine environment.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl

Comment: It works when the app listens on 8080. But doesn't when say its listening to 3000 even after adding the concerned rule in firewalls settings.

Comment: Your app doesn't bind directly to the port on the guest VM, as it runs inside a container. Firewall rules also only affect direct connections to the VM, which is not what you do when using the App Engine service. Don't confuse App Engine with Compute Engine. With that being said, you can change the port your app listens on inside the container by setting the PORT environment variable, as per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#environment_variables).

Comment: Note that it's not possible to forward port 3000 from the appspot.com frontend - this is the subject of an open [public issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/35898669). If you require this functionality (eg. for implementing a WebSocket API) a better alternative for the time being is to host your server on [Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/).